# Access batchDuration in StreamingContext using public API?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to access `batchDuration` field in [`StreamingContext`](https://github.com/apache-spark/spark/blob/25b71d8c15572f0f2b951c827c169f8c65f726ad/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.scala#L65). I don't see any public API that exposes this value. How to get access to this field? This is basically the window size of streaming job. My code doesn't have access to user defined job to get the value from there.

Answer (score 1):

Create your **class** or **object** inside `package org.apache.spark.streaming` package and then use following code to get **batchDuration** from **StreamingContext**

```
val ssc: StreamingContext = ???
ssc.graph.batchDuration
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using this approach and then mix the trait into my own abstract base class. since `ssc.graph.batchDuration` is only accessible in `package org.apache.spark.streaming`